# Where does (function instance).prototype field point to by default?

Tags: javascript

Can't find answer to this simple question.

```
var fun1 = function() {};
```

where does `fun1.prototype` point to? Keep in mind I haven't set `fun1.prototype = someObject` nor `someObject.constructor = fun1`. So where does the variable `fun1.prototype` refer to by default?

--- edit 1 ---

Got it: if you create new function `fun1`, Javascript implementation will create a new object `{ constructor: fun1 }` under `fun1.prototype`.

I was thinking maybe it was pointing to some predefined object like `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Why don't you check it at F12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to an object that has a `constructor` property pointing back to the function. Something like

```
{
  constructor: fun1,
}
```

Comment: But I haven't set someObject.constructor = fun1 nor fun1.prototype = someObject. I am assuming Javascript engine will create a new empty object under fun1.prototype?

Comment: Yes, all this is done by JavaScript itself when you create a function. You asked for what its default value is and this is it.

Comment: @potato300: You can use an arrow function if you don't want a default `.prototype` object